# Move two matches (no [lateral-thinking])

Tags: visual, matches

Move two matches to make the following equation correct:

[image: 4+9/3=4/2]

Despite it commonly applying to puzzles of this kind, there is no [lateral-thinking] tag here, so no spelling out numbers, no turning the picture upside down, only such (decimal!) digits as can be found on a 7-segment indicator, no superscripts or subscripts (I could imagine someone strategically placing primes and declaring that the derivative of a constant function is zero), the equation must remain an equation etc.

To the best of my knowledge the solution is unique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is like this:

> [image]
>  I've moved the gray matchsticks to the blue locations, and now the equation reads "4 - 8/3 = 4/3".

Comment: My program that generated this must be flawed, the intended solution was less straightforward :−(

Answer (score 5):

How about

> $9-3/3=4 \times 2$

where the matchsticks that are moved are taken from

> the top left of the 9, making a 3, and the plus sign

and they are moved to

> the top of the 4, making a 9 with no tail, and the second $/$, making a $\times$

Comment: Hmm, way too many solutions when I erroneously determined there was only one. I’ll try to compose a higher-quality puzzle next time!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Or, is the intended solution

> 5-9/3=4/2?

By

> (moving the sticks from "+" and "4" to form "5")

Answer (score 1):

Also,

> `4 - 6 / 3 ≡ 4 / 2`

by

> 1. `+ 9` becomes `- 8`
>  2. `8` and `=` become `6` and `≡`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also

> turn the 9 into a 6, and then take the vertical match from the + and burn it.